# lake shore, sea coast, river side

Tags: vocabulary

What do you call these three things in German?

lake shore, sea coast, river side

Here are my suggestions:

- lake shore = Seeufer
- sea coast = Meeresküste
- river side = Flussseite

Am I right?

Comment: *Es lächelt der See, er ladet zum Bade,
Der Knabe schlief ein am grünen Gestade*

Comment: 'thank you' messages in the answers are not needed.

Answer (score 3):

This are the most common terms:

- lake shore = Seeufer
- sea coast = Meeresküste
- river side = Flussufer

»Flussseite« ist very uncommon.

»Meeresufer« ist possible, but »Meeresküste« or just »Küste« is better. All three can be just »Ufer« (you don't need to say of which waters if it is clear from the context).

Comment: _Flussseite_ is uncommon but can be used when someone has a large house and wants to express that the living room is "zur Flussseite hin" (to the river side) while the kitchen is in the opposite direction.

Comment: I'm just wondering whether you would only use "Ufer" for a "Meer" if said "Meer" is actually just a lake -- the Steinhuder Meer for example.

Answer (score 2):

> lake shore = Seeufer

Correct.

> sea coast = Meeresküste

Most Germans would only say "*Küste*". "*Meeresküste*" sounds a bit strange.

> river side = Flussseite

I think this is not the word you are searching for.

If you are talking about the question if a city or a country is located on the **left or the right side of a river** you can use the word "*Flusseite*" (although most Germans would say "*Seite des Flusses*" in this case).

If you want to say that something is directly beneath the river you would use the word "*Ufer*" - the same word you use for a lake.

So the word you are searching is probably "*Flussufer*".

Comment: How about if the river is not a Flus but a big one - a Strom ?

Comment: @cornejo, a very big 'Fluss' is in German still called a 'Fluss'. 'Strom' is only rarely used.

Comment: @cornejo As an extension to Iris' answer I would say the word "*Strom*" is normally used in certain contexts only. In contexts when you use the word "*river side*" you would definitely use the Word "*Fluss*".